# Sowing your field with 2 different seeds "kilayim" does this apply to outside of Israel as well?

Tags: halacha, chutz-laaretz, kilayim-forbidden-mixture

Today i ran into a relative that was doing this and mentioned the forbidden law of doing this, he then replied to me that outside of Israel it is allowed. Is this true?
And if so does all of judaism accept this?

Comment: Basically it's fine if no grape are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you talk about Kilaey hakerem and kilaey zeraym. See Mishna Kilayim (8, 1):

> כִּלְאֵי הַכֶּרֶם אֲסוּרִין מִלִּזְרֹעַ, וּמִלְּקַיֵּם, וַאֲסוּרִין בַּהֲנָאָה. כִּלְאֵי זְרָעִים, אֲסוּרִים מִלִּזְרֹעַ וּמִלְּקַיֵּם, וּמֻתָּרִין בַּאֲכִילָה, וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן בַּהֲנָאָה.
>
> this mishna shows that Kilaey zeraym are allowed for profit and eating.

See the last Mishna of Masechet Orla (3, 9):

> סְפֵק עָרְלָה, בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל אָסוּר, וּבְסוּרְיָא מֻתָּר, וּבְחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ יוֹרֵד וְלוֹקֵחַ, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא יִרְאֶנּוּ לוֹקֵט. כֶּרֶם נָטוּעַ יָרָק, וְיָרָק נִמְכָּר חוּצָה לוֹ, בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׁרָאֵל אָסוּר, וּבְסוּרְיָא מֻתָּר, וּבְחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ יוֹרֵד וְלוֹקֵט, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא יִלְקֹט בַּיָּד. הֶחָדָשׁ, אָסוּר מִן הַתּוֹרָה בְּכָל מָקוֹם . וְהָעָרְלָה, הֲלָכָה. וְהַכִּלְאַיִם, מִדִּבְרֵי סוֹפְרִים:
>
> Here some rules are explained concerning Kilae Hakerem outside of Erets Yisrael (OOEY). For Kilae Hakerem there is a rabbinic prohibition in OOEY and for Kilae Zeraym it is totally allowed OOEY (Following comment of Bartenura)

And the penultimate Mishna of the first chapter of Kiddushin (1, 9):

> כָּל מִצְוָה שֶׁהִיא תְלוּיָה בָאָרֶץ אֵינָהּ נוֹהֶגֶת אֶלָּא בָאָרֶץ. וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ תְּלוּיָה בָאָרֶץ נוֹהֶגֶת בֵּין בָּאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ, חוּץ מִן הָעָרְלָה וְכִלְאָיִם. רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר אוֹמֵר, אַף מִן הֶחָדָשׁ:
>
> Here is also mentioned that Kilae Hakerem is prohibited OOEY by a rabbinical prohibition (Bartenura)

#### So we can begin to understand what your relative replied.

Gemara and Rishonim treat your question and we will try to explain.

> Tosfot in kiddushin 36b:
>
> ומן הירושלמי שהבאתי יש להוכיח דערלה וכלאים נוהגים בשל עובדי כוכבים וכן  ‏

Tosfot stated that Kilaey Hakerem is prohibited OOEY even from a land of a non-Jew.

---

Kilaey Hakerem: to sow 1 grain of wheat, 1 of barley and 1 grape seed in one hand jet.

Kilaey Zerayim: to sow 1 grain of wheat, 1 of barley.

All this is for flagellation. But there is a prohibition to maintain even if I have not swathed.

The word **Kerem** is Vineyard.

The word **Zerayim** is plant species (edible plants or seed)

Comment: What is kilayi hakerem? And what is kilayi hazerem?

Comment: @TheTribeOfJudah Kerem is Vineyard
Zerayim is

Comment: @TheTribeOfJudah The answer is fixed with translation at the end